# Select all used range except header

Tags: excel, vba

good day.
Thanks for always responding.Please I am trying to extract all used range without headers. first of all i filter and then  i use this formula below to select the filtered data. The formula excludes the header in row A and selects all filtered data below. but the issue now is that when there is no filtered data the formula cant find anything to select and it fails.

'Selects all filled rows except headers

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Set rng = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)

rng.Select
```

I wish the formula was able to know that nothing is visible on the filtered sheet so it doesn't have to try to select

Warm Regards

Comment: `Set rng = rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)` will always refer to the `UsedRange` without the header and `rng.Select` will always select this range even if you think it only selected the filtered rows.  Question is, what do you really want to `select`.

Comment: [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38410389/9808063) .. It shows how to handle error if there is no range after filter

Comment: Hey Storax , thank you. I want to select only the range of the filtered results while excluding the headers . thank you @Naresh Bhople I am checking it out too..thank you too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [excel vba - Select all filtered rows except header after autofilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410056/excel-vba-select-all-filtered-rows-except-header-after-autofilter)

Comment: Hello Storax,  yes it solves my problem. thanks a lot ... i really appreciate. thanks everyone